# Как установить выделение цветом в xml тэг ripple

Tags: android, android-selector

Нужно в xml настроить чтобы выделенные элементы отображались серым цветом, с версии android 21, использую ripple. Как в ripple это настроить?

drawable\selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorGrey" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorGrey" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

drawbale-v21\selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorGrey">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@color/colorGrey"/>
</ripple>
```

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите аналог  `<item android:drawable="@color/colorGrey" android:state_selected="true"/>` для риппла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такое с [en-so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30136883/3212712)

1. Создайте отдельный файл с рипплом `ripple_effect.xml` в папке `drawable-v21`

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="@color/green_primary">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/green_primary"/>
</ripple>
```

2. Используйте его в обычном селекторе наряду с проставлением цвета для состояния выбрано

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
            android:drawable="@color/green_selected"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ripple_effect"/>
</selector>
```